# Get total number of tweets in twitter using apache spark scala

Tags: scala, twitter, apache-spark

I am new to apache-spark and I want to find out the total number of tweets posted across the world in twitter for every 10 seconds span of time. I wrote a small snippet to get the tag in twitter. Now I need to find out the total count of all the tweets in twitter.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

```
import java.io._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import StreamingContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter._

object TwitterPopularTags {

        def main(args: Array[String]) {
                val (master, filters) = (args(0), args.slice(5, args.length))

                        // Twitter Authentication credentials
                        System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerKey", "xxxx")
                        System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerSecret","xxxx")
                        System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessToken", "xxxx")
                        System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessTokenSecret", "xxxx")


                        val ssc = new StreamingContext(master,    "TwitterPopularTags",Seconds(10),
               System.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), StreamingContext.jarOfClass(this.getClass))

                        val tweets = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None)

                        val statuses = tweets.map(status => status.getText())

                        val words = statuses.flatMap(status => status.split(" ")) 
                        val hashTags = words.filter(word => word.startsWith("#"))

                        val tagCounts = hashTags.window(Seconds(100), Seconds(10)).countByValue()

                        tagCounts.print()
```

}

Comment: Note that with a standard account, you will only get a small fraction of the tweets sent across the world. You will need a twitter firehose subscription and a really large cluster to achieve that goal.

Comment: You just forgot to start the streaming process with `ssc.start`

Answer (score 0):

RDD `tweets` contains all the tweets received.

`tweets.count` gives the total count.

Comment: println(tweets.count) is giving an error  No output streams registered, so nothing to execute
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: No output streams registered, so nothing to execute ... Is there any method to get tweets count per 10 seconds in a better way.

Comment: please try ** statuses.count **. Also provide the datatype of hashTags and statuses RDD

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot to start the streaming process with `ssc.start`